# What is the difference between AssetImage and Image.asset - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

In my application, I use these 2 classes but I don't know which one I should prioritize.

```
Image.asset('icons/heart.png')
AssetImage('icons/hear.png')
```

Maybe there is one who fetches the image faster.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`Image` is a `StatefulWidget` and `Image.asset` is just a named constructor,  you can use it directly on your widget tree.

`AssetImage` is an `ImageProvider` which is responsible for obtaining the image of the specified path.

If you check the source code of the `Image.asset` you will find that it's using AssetImage to get the image.

```
  Image.asset(String name, {
      Key key,
      AssetBundle bundle,
      this.semanticLabel,
      this.excludeFromSemantics = false,
      double scale,
      this.width,
      this.height,
      this.color,
      this.colorBlendMode,
      this.fit,
      this.alignment = Alignment.center,
      this.repeat = ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
      this.centerSlice,
      this.matchTextDirection = false,
      this.gaplessPlayback = false,
      String package,
      this.filterQuality = FilterQuality.low,
    }) : image = scale != null
           ? ExactAssetImage(name, bundle: bundle, scale: scale, package: package)
           : AssetImage(name, bundle: bundle, package: package),
         assert(alignment != null),
         assert(repeat != null),
         assert(matchTextDirection != null),
         super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @diegoveloper
From `flutter version  2.5`, it is recommended to use the `Image StatefulWidget` with the **const** modifier which is impossible with `Image.asset`.  However, you'll need to provide the `image path` as a parameter to the `AssetImage` object, where this object is the value of the **named parameter** 'image' of the `Image StatefulWidget`, like so.

```dart
  Image(
        image: AssetImage('asset/dice1.png'),
       )
```

From the **recommended** Dart tutorial book *Dart Apprentice* `const and final` modifiers on objects **reduce subsequent compile-time and runtime.**
Therefore for **clean and few lines** of code, use `Image.asset`, but for **fast and CPU-friendly code**, use `Image StatefulWidget`.